# PNG files transparency background problem

Tags: transparency, png, background, file-format

I'm trying to use PNG files for creating and I have the next problem:

[image]

As you can see, when I import or paste the IMG, the background of PNG 'is not actually a background'. Is like background has the squares of transparency but actually is like white. I'm not sure if I'm explaining well because I find it a little bit weird.

The indicated zone in the IMG happens when I select this rectangle and I delete, so it shows the properly transparency background.

Why it's happening?

Comment: This is often done when images are for sale. That way the checkerboard shows what *will* be transparent when you purchase the image(s), but it's not *actually* transparent in the preview before the purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file has been saved incorrectly. That's about all we can say. To get the checker background, best guess is someone took a screenshot of an image from inside a graphics app, rather than saved the file itself.

Screenshot from Photoshop, as png -

[image]

File quickly cleaned up & saved correctly as png with transparency, which, of course, will show with a white background in here. Try dragging it to your desktop

[image]

Comment: It worked, and I have understood the problem. Thank you!